# Parity of function (simple question)

Tags: calculus

Is correct to ask if $f(x)={\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$ is an even or odd function?
How to define the parity of a function?

Comment: What does an "even" or "odd" function mean to you?  What happens when you plug in $-x$ instead of $x$?

Comment: Why not type "even and odd functions" into google?

Answer (score 4):

A function $f$ is defined to be **even** if $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ such that $f(x)$ is actually defined. It is **odd** if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$.

In this case, we have

$$f(-x) = \sqrt{1 - (-x)^2} = \sqrt{1 - x^2} = f(x)$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I added a note regarding the domain. Thanks.